# Close question as too verbose

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I suggest another close category is added for questions: "too verbose" or even "TMI". Quite often I see a question that contains way too much information and it is extremely hard to pass through and get to the important part([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608350/probability-of-a-anagram-hash-collision)). It is not the job of the one that answers the question to pass through a large question, but a job of the one that asks to ask a short and comprehensible question. Closing a question for that reason will force the author to improve the question. I believe users of SoF and mostly using downvotes in similar cases, which is not the best option IMHO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We are actually fighting the other side of the coin - questions that do not have enough information.

Questions that have too much information are easy to deal with - **you edit the superfluous information**. Or ask the OP to do so in a comment.

---

I disagree with this feature request as questions with too much information are actually **answerable**, whereas questions that have too little, are not.

Comment: I try to change the active part in making the question answerable. I believe it is authors responsibility to make the question readable and answerable. In my experience posting a comment is not very efficient to achieve that. However I agree that such question is answerable.

Answer (score 0):

I might downvote a question that's "too verbose" and therefore confusing (and leave a comment to this effect).

But closing is "too strong." As Oded pointed out, "too verbose" is a far lesser fault than the opposite because it is a lot more fixable.